# Prometheus alert manager AWS definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, prometheus, monitoring, prometheus-alertmanager

I am trying to configure the Prometheus alert manager running on my EKS cluster via AWS workspaces. Now from what I've read so far that's the only way to update the configuration and it's not possible to do it via eksctl/helm.

Now there are two things you can do through it:

1. Rules Management - It asks you to upload a .yaml with namespaces "Namespace contains rule groups that define recording and alerting rules." - here goes the rules yaml file, and I am kinda ok with that basic explanation they gave out, yet it's not that much and I wish there was more: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prometheus/latest/userguide/AMP-ruler-rulesfile.html
2. Alert manager - "Add an alert manager definition to start routing, inhibiting, and silencing alerts." pretty much self explanatory, (important: I am using slack as the receiver however, I am doing this without configuring SNS and Lambda as [AWS requires you to do!](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prometheus/latest/userguide/AMP-alertmanager-config.html#:%7E:text=The%20only%20receiver%20currently%20supported%20is%20Amazon%20Simple%20Notification%20Service%20(Amazon%20SNS)) ). Now when I get to the point to upload the .yaml over there I get "Malformed Alertmanager definition." and this is a verified valid yaml file!

The config is as follows:

```
alertmanager_config: |
  route:
    group_by: ['alertname']
    group_wait: 10s
    group_interval: 10s
    repeat_interval: 1m
    receiver: 'slack_notifications'
  receivers:
    - name: 'slack_notifications'
      slack_configs:
    - api_url: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/ooga/booga/key'
        channel: '#slack-monitoring'
        send_resolved: true
  inhibit_rules:
    - source_match:
        severity: 'critical'
      target_match:
        severity: 'warning'
      equal: ['alertname', 'dev', 'instasnce']
```

I've tried different variations of the above but none worked...

Has anyone dealt with this at all and successfully configured Prometheus via AWS Workspaces so far? There is nothing on the internet about it, and I understand that this is a fairly new service AWS has released but there is very little to none community support for it :(

Cheers,
Vlatko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only alert receiver currently supported in Amazon Managed Service
> for Prometheus is Amazon Simple Notification Service (Amazon SNS)

From [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prometheus/latest/userguide/AMP-alertmanager-receiver.html)

Also, [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prometheus/latest/userguide/AMP-alertmanager-receiver-config.html) document is useful because of unsupported properties and required block in sns_configs.

Comment: Hey Dmitrii, thanks for coming back. So this just confirms my suspicions around it that in fact it is only possible to configure it via SNS and then to send out to Slack or whatever receiver I would prefer on the other end.

Comment: hey @vlatko, I use AMP in production extensively. 
Can confirm, this answer is correct.